# php, is fgetcsv the best way to append files in a semicolon database in a text file?

Tags: php, html

I'm confused on the best way to proceed... Here's a very small sample of my database.

```
SCD 0; TEST ; wfbscd13 ; 158.140.161.55 ; 16:08:47 ;
SCD 1; #ff9900 ; wfbscd13 ; 158.140.161.55 ; 16:08:47 ;
SCD 2; #ff9900 ; wfbscd13 ; 158.140.161.55 ; 16:08:47 ;
SCD 3; #ff9900 ; wfbscd13 ; 158.140.161.55 ; 16:08:47 ;
SCD 4; #ff9900 ; wfbscd13 ; 158.140.161.55 ; 16:08:47 ;
```

I created a variable to get the information with this...

```
<?php

$statusled = array();
  if (($handle = fopen($statfile, "r")) !== FALSE)
     {
         while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE)
          {
         if(substr(trim($data[0]), 0, 3) == 'SCD')
      {
        $board = trim($data[0]);
        $status = $data[1];
        $statusled[ $board ] = $status;
    }
}
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

The info in the database as an example is test from this variable.
What can I do to this variable to make it reverse the process? In this case I can echo the results wherever I want, but now I want to add to the database...

Am I close?

William